# Como manter os dados de uma variável, ao iniciar uma Actitivy, e ao voltar, carregar o valor?

Tags: java, android

eu estou com o seguinte problema, e gostaria de ajuda de todos por gentileza.

Tenho uma activity, em que, SE APERTAR O btn1, acontecerá
boolean mesa1 = true;

Assim como pra btn2... sucessivamente.

Quando mesa1 for true, o botao muda de cor, e abre uma nova activity.
Quando eu faço isso no btn2, o botao muda de cor, e abre a activity.
Só que ao voltar, o btn1 nao está mais com a cor alterada, ou seja, o mesa1 está false;

Como manter: boolean mesa1 = true; independentemente de quantas activiys eu abrir ?
[image: Imagem inicial]
[image: Ao clicar na primeira mesa, mesa1 = true, e abre a activity de pedidos]
[image: A mesa ficou cinza, pois mesa1 = true]
[image: Fazendo a mesma coisa, agora com a mesa2]
[image: funcionou, mas perdi o valor true da mesa1]

Comment: O valor das variaveis deve estar sendo mantidas, pelo que parece é que ao voltar na activicty principal as imagens são resetadas, logo vc deve fazer uma checagem em todas as mesas. exemplo, crie um método que faz uma checagem em todas as mesas, se mesa1 é igual a true, então troque de imagem, e assim sucessivamente para todas as mesas.

Comment: Se as variaveis não estão sendo mantidas, o problema pode ser o escopo em que você criou elas, ou ao chamar a nova acitivity de realizar pedido vc pode estar finalizando a activity principal com o método finish. Veja se não pode ser isso. Sem o código fonte é muito dificil saber o que pode estar acontecendo, são apenas subjeções.

Comment: Nao, nao tem finish(), cara, eu so preciso saber COMO manter os dados. O meu problema nao é um "erro", nao tem como eu mandar o código sendo que eu nao fiz nada a respeito de manter dados.. é isso que eu preciso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma solução seria.

Use o atributo tag do botão para  salvar o estado dele.
no xml do botão inicie o atributo tag com zero `android:tag="0"`.

Toda vez que você alterar o estado do botão vc deve atualizar o seu tag para 1 ou 0,  logo `btn1.setTag("1");`

na activity principal vc deve implementar o método onResume, e checar todas os botão se estão marcados ou não.

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
   super.onResume();
   if(btn1.getTag().equals("1"))
      //altera imagem
   if(btn2.getTag().equals("1"))
      //altera imagem
   if(btn3.getTag().equals("1"))
      //altera imagem
}
```

Agora toda vez que a activity principal ser recarregada ela vai checar os estados de todos os botões .

> **Observação:** é claro que esse não é o melhor modo de guardar esse tipo
>   de informação na maioria dos casos, pois eu creio que um aplicativo como esse no futuro
>   concerteza dependerá de um servidor, que estará responsável por
>   notificar os celulares que uma mesa foi finalizado o pedido, essa
>   resposta é valida apenas para responder a sua pergunta, que ficou um
>   pouco ampla de mais, pois tem varias formas de resolver este problema.

Comment: Exato, precisaria de um servidor para o aplicativo funcionar em um comercio MESMO. Mas como apenas um trabalho de escola, qualquer coisa funcionando está bom. Muito obrigado por ensinar uma coisa que eu ainda nao conhecia.